# Accessing Facebook Graph API without login

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've seen that with Javascript API and via GET requests, it is possible to get public posts from FanPages.
What i'm trying to acomplish is an Android Native App that doesn't ask user to get logged and with the FB App access token gets and shows the posts from the FB Page.
I'm wondering if this is possible via Android FB API as I can accomplish this via urls like

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{page_id}/feed?fields=message,picture&limit=10&access_token={your_acces_token}
```

When i'm trying this with Android Graph API, without user loging,

AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()

returns null

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to do this and they are both [documented here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#apptokens).

The simpler method is to simply concatenate your AppID and AppSecret (found in your Facebook developer dashboard) with a "|" character like so: 'App ID' + '|' + 'App Secret'

**BE WARNED!**
This will expose your App's Private Credentials in Client Side Code if someone decides to look carefully.  Therefore it is much safer to setup a private backend server to act as a proxy for your mobile application's user-less access to the graph API.

You could set up an API in any language of your choice with a single public route that simply copies the request it receives, appends the credentials, sends the request to Facebook, and pipes Facebook's response back to the original requestor.

For Example:

**Without Access Token:**

Mobile App --->  http://www.YourServerDomain/{page_id}/feed?fields=message,picture&limit=10

**With Access Token:**

Your Server ---> http://graph.facebook.com/{page_id}/feed?fields=message,picture&limit=10&access_token=AppID|AppSecret

**Response Pipeline**

Facebook ---> API RESULT ---> Your Server ---> API RESULT ---> Mobile App

Comment: So it will always have to be done via pure HTTP? No way of doing this via Android FB SDK?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Android SDK but looking at the documentation you could probably do something like this:
String appToken = "AppID" + "|" + "AppSecret";
AccessToken token = new AccessToken(appToken, "AppID", null, null, null, null, null, null);
GraphRequest req = new GraphRequest(token, "page_id/feed");

Check out the documentation here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/

Comment: Is there any public server that implements `Without Access Token` way?

Answer (score 4):

I was struggling with the same for a while and after hours of research I came up with this ([source](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/page/feed)):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
  AppEventsLogger.activateApp(getApplication());

  AccessToken at         = new AccessToken(getString(R.string.facebook_access_token), getString(R.string.facebook_app_id), getString(R.string.facebook_page_id), null, null, null, null, null);
  Bundle      parameters = new Bundle();
  parameters.putString("fields", "message,created_time,link,full_picture");
  new GraphRequest(at, "/" + at.getUserId() + "/feed", parameters, HttpMethod.GET, new GraphRequest.Callback() {

    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {

      Log.i(this.getClass().getName(), "onCompleted " + response.getRawResponse());
    }
  }).executeAsync();
}
```

I assume you already have a page access token. I created mine with the graph explorer from facebook. Here is a tutorial on how to create a never expiring one:
[How to get a never expiring Facebook Page Access Token](https://www.rocketmarketinginc.com/blog/get-never-expiring-facebook-page-access-token/) (look for the 2016 Method)

As far as I know, the extended token does not expire as long as it is used. But I am not sure about that. I think I red this somewhere in the facebook api docs but cannot find it anymore.

There are a lot other parameters you can set. See here [Page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/) and look for 'Fields'

Hope this clumsy solution is helpfull to someone.